# wifi connected but not transferring any packets Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

The charity I work for has a number of Dell Latitude  E6420/E6430/E6230 on which WiFi doesn't work using modern wireless APs when Edubuntu 14.04.1 is installed.  They work fine on an old D-Link 802.11G router that does not support 802.11N.

I have researched on this and other sites and the problem seems to be associated with the newer 802.11N protocol, but none of the suggested fixes seems to work, including updating the Linux kernel.

I'm not a Linux Guru but I have downloaded and run the suggested wireless-info script and created wireless-info.txt with it disconnected from the D-Link and "connected" to my newer Draytek 2920n router.

The output of the script is available [in this paste](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BNt9gZy3QM/). My wireless device is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0082] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Grateful if someone can suggest a reliable fix for this!

Regards
Andrew

Comment: Could you also try a live version of a more recent Ubuntu version?

Comment: I can try that but remember we are aiming to use Edubuntu which has not gone beyond 14.04 for whatever reason.  I have other Dells that I have subsequently upgraded to v16  but I don't have them at hand to see if the WiFi works.  One of the suggested fixes for this problem was to issue a command that disables 11n in iwlwifi but it this instance that didn't work.  And remember that it works fine on 11g routers - I have now tried 2 and proved that it works reliably on these so it must be something to do with Ubuntu's handling of the 11n protocols I think.

Comment: Update - I have now upgraded the machines to Ubuntu 16 and, sadly, neither of them can connect to a modern router.  Same issue.  On some of my other Dell laptops it DOES work in 16, but not these two.  Where do I go now with this issue - I need to get these fixed and delivered to the end users?  And just to prove the point I am posting this comment using an older Netgear that uses 802.11g!

Comment: Correction to last - it mostly does not work on other Dells either.  I have even tried it with Linux Mint now - same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it. The solution is **to disable 802.11n** with this command in a terminal prompt:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" |sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Then reboot.

Now it works fine on my Draytek router.

Thanks to everyone who offered advice.